# no matching function for call to 'transform

Tags: c++

can anyone tell me what is the mistake in this program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str = "Now";

    transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), toupper);

    cout<<str;

    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
"no matching function for call to 'transform(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors."
```

Comment: Try `..., ::toupper);`

Comment: Try `#include <locale>` and then `std::ctype::toupper` as an argument.

Comment: When you're dealing with errors you can't figure out, it might be beneficial to compile without `-Wfatal-errors` because that switch can suppress relevant information.

Answer (score 12):

There are two functions with name `toupper`. One from `cctype` header:

```
int toupper( int ch );
```

And second from `locale` header:

```
charT toupper( charT ch, const locale& loc );
```

Compiler can't deduce which function should be used, since you allow namespace `std`. You should use *scope resolution operator*(`::`) to choose function defined in global space:

```
transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::toupper);
```

Or, better: *Do not use `using namespace std`.*

---

Thanks to @Praetorian -

> This is probably the cause of the error, but adding `::` may not always
>   work. If you include `cctype` `toupper` is not guaranteed to exist in the
>   global namespace. A cast can provide the necessary disambiguation
>   `static_cast<int(*)(int)>(std::toupper)`

So, the call should look like:

```
std::transform
(
    str.begin(), str.end(),
    str.begin(),
    static_cast<int(*)(int)>(std::toupper)
);
```

Comment: This is probably the cause of the error, but adding `::` may not always work. If you include *cctype* `toupper` is not guaranteed to exist in the global namespace. A cast can provide the necessary disambiguation `static_cast<int(*)(int)>(std::toupper)`

Answer (score 3):

In order to use `toupper`, you need to include header file:

```
#include <cctype>
```

You also need to include header file:

```
#include <string>
```

The problem is the `std::toupper` takes `int` as parameter, while `std::transform` will pass `char` into the function, therefore, it has a problem (by courtesy of @juanchopanza).

You may try to use:

```
 #include <functional>
 std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), std::ptr_fun<int, int>(std::toupper));
```

See example code from [std::transform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)

Or you can implement your own `toupper` that takes `char` as argument.

Comment: I include <cctype> but it is of no use

Comment: @user2413497 try to check the link I included? It has complete example at the bottom of the link with explanations.

Comment: @juanchopanza I agree. I will update the post now.

Comment: @juanchopanza, are you sure? Last argument for `std::transform` function is templated. `std::transform` doesn't care, accept it `int` or `char`. From cppreference: `The type  Type must be such that an object of type InputIt can be dereferenced and then implicitly converted to  Type. The type  Ret must be such that an object of type OutputIt can be dereferenced and assigned a value of type  Ret. `

Comment: @soon do you have a good explanation why it would not work with `std::toupper`?

Comment: @juanchopanza, yes, I do. You could see it in my answer. In short: there are could be two reasons. First: compiler can't choose between `std::toupper` from `cctype` and `locale` headers. Second: `cctype` doesn't included, but `std::toupper` from `locale` is templated. Compiler cant infer template argument.

Comment: @soon Yeah, you are right. In my test, the `<locale>` overload must have crept in, even if I didn't include `<locale>`.

Answer (score 0):

As the compiler has buried in its error message, the real problem is that toupper is an overloaded function, and the compiler can't figure out which one you want. There's the C toupper(int) function which may or may not be a macro (may not in C++, but does the C library care?), and there's std::toupper(char, locale) from  (pulled in by  without doubt), which you made available globally with your `using namespace std;`.

Tony's solution works because he accidentally resolved the overloading issue with his separate function.